# Form block messes up when rendered multiple times using v-for in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js

I'm trying to render one form multiple times for each entry in list of dictionaries in Vue.js, however what happens is when I change my value in the second entry, the value(of the radio button input) in the first entry gets changed instead, I couldn't figure out why is this happening.

Here is snippet of the code I use:

```
<div v-for="movie in watchList" :key="movie.movieTitle" class="movieBlock">
          <p>Rate this movie</p>
          <form>
            <div class="rate" style="display: inline-block;">
              <input style="visibility: hidden;" type="radio" id="star5" v-model="movie.newReviewRating" name="rate" value="5" />
              <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
              <input style="visibility: hidden;" type="radio" id="star4" v-model="movie.newReviewRating" name="rate" value="4" />
              <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
              <input style="visibility: hidden;" type="radio" id="star3" v-model="movie.newReviewRating" name="rate" value="3" />
              <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
              <input style="visibility: hidden;" type="radio" id="star2" v-model="movie.newReviewRating" name="rate" value="2" />
              <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
              <input style="visibility: hidden;" type="radio" id="star1" v-model="movie.newReviewRating" name="rate" value="1" />
              <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
            </div>
          </form>   
      </div>
```

Once again, the issue is that when I try to change the selected input for the second entry rendered, the first entry gets changed value, and I cannot understand why this happens.

I can upload pictures if the problem is not clear.

Comment: remove the ids, because you can't have the same ID more than once. It will probably solve your problem. I couldn't see any other issue.

Comment: Thank you Bülent! This helped me a lot and fixed my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like  Bülent Akgül said in the comments, you can't have an id repeated, so you'll need to change the id from each element and change the attribute `for` of each label.

So the problem is because you are using a label for attribute what that does is trigger the event on the element that has the id of the for, because all the id's and for were the same for each loop, it always trigger the same movie.

```
<div v-for="movie in watchList" :key="movie.movieTitle" class="movieBlock">
  <p>Rate this movie</p>
  <form>
    <div class="rate" style="display: inline-block;">
      <input style="visibility: hidden;" type="radio" :id="`rating-${movie.movieTitle}-star5`" v-model="movie.newReviewRating" name="rate-${movie.movieTitle}" value="5" />
      <label :for="`rating-${movie.movieTitle}-star5`" title="text">5 stars</label>
      <input style="visibility: hidden;" type="radio" :id="`rating-${movie.movieTitle}-star4`" v-model="movie.newReviewRating" name="rate-${movie.movieTitle}" value="4" />
      <label :for="`rating-${movie.movieTitle}-star4`" title="text">4 stars</label>
      <input style="visibility: hidden;" type="radio" :id="`rating-${movie.movieTitle}-star3`" v-model="movie.newReviewRating" name="rate-${movie.movieTitle}" value="3" />
      <label :for="`rating-${movie.movieTitle}-star3`" title="text">3 stars</label>
      <input style="visibility: hidden;" type="radio" :id="`rating-${movie.movieTitle}-star2`" v-model="movie.newReviewRating" name="rate-${movie.movieTitle}" value="2" />
      <label :for="`rating-${movie.movieTitle}-star2`" title="text">2 stars</label>
      <input style="visibility: hidden;" type="radio" :id="`rating-${movie.movieTitle}-star1`" v-model="movie.newReviewRating" name="rate-${movie.movieTitle}" value="1" />
      <label :for="`rating-${movie.movieTitle}-star1`" title="text">1 star</label>
    </div>
  </form>   
</div>
```